# Data not showing up in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I've looked at every thread I could find on how to get a json feed into my google chart, but nothing seems to be working or the threads are slightly different from my problem.

Update: I'm trying to parse my json feed to only show certain columns. For example, my feed has a Actual and Goal column. I want my chart to only show the Actual column. I need the goal column for filtering reasons on the back end, so when the feed updates from the database it knows which records to pull.

After carefully following the json format for Google charts and figuring out a way to add the data, i'm am still unsuccessful in getting the actual data to show up. What's weird is that the graph shows up, it just doesn't have any data in it. I get no errors in my console.I've made sure my json string is valid, it is. I've tried logging my json feed to make sure that the information is being passed correctly and it is. The columns are added, as in the code, but the rows just won't show up.

I believe that in my data.addRow line, i'm not traversing correctly, but can't seem to figure out how to correctly get down to the specific cell.

```
function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
      url: "--",
      dataType:"json",
      success: function (result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Quarter'); 
        data.addColumn('number', 'Actual'); 

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          data.addRow([result.rows[i], result.rows[i], result.rows[i]]);
        }
```

Here is my json feed:

```
{ "cols":[ {"label":"Quarter", "type":"string"},{"label": "Actual", "type":"number"}, {"label":"Goal","type":"number"}], "rows":[ {"c":[{"v":"Q1"}, {"v":22}, {"v":30}]}, 
 {"c":[{"v":"Q2"}, {"v":24}, {"v":30}]}, 
 {"c":[{"v":"Q3"}, {"v":27}, {"v":30}]} 
]}
```

Comment: You can't add rows with json format, json format is made to load the data by json, doing `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json); ` If you want to add it manually, you need to traverse the `c` in rows as well

Comment: Thanks for the help. yes, this does work. But, I think in my own attempt to dumb down the result data. I forgot that what I need to do is parse the data. For example, My "Goal" column would be in the feed, but not show up in the actual chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build the DataTable with your raw JSON:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
```

and then use a DataView to filter out your "Goal" column:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1]);
```

Draw your chart using the DataView instead of the DataTable:

```
chart.draw(view, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your response data from ajax call (as Json formated) to your DataTable

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(responseData);
```